# Using Server side Blazor, how do you impersonate a user using windows authentication when connecting to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, impersonation

I've set up row-level security in my database and I'm trying to create a connection to the database. I'm having trouble doing this because I can't seem to make a request to the SQL Server as the requesting client.

The application is built using Blazor and my database connection is done using EF Core.

The server side method used to run a query on the DB is the following

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public WeatherForecastService(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IDbContextFactory<SqlDboDbContext> dbo)
{
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _dbo = dbo;
        var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        Name1 = context.User.Identity.Name;

        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AccessToken, () =>
        {
            Name2 = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlDboDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("SQL_Server"));
            using (var cntx = new SqlDboDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                Markets = cntx.Markets.ToArray();
                t1 = cntx.Transactions.ToArray();
            }
        });
}
```

`Name1` and `Name2` both display the client but when I take a look at the query ran on the DB using

```
SELECT sdest.DatabaseName 
    ,sdes.session_id
    ,sdes.[host_name]
    ,sdes.[program_name]
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.login_name
    ,sdes.original_login_name
    ,sdes.login_time
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdest.Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
    ) sdest

--and sdes.nt_user_name = '' -- Put the username here !
ORDER BY sdec.session_id
```

All fields show the user that I've set for the application pool.

Various connection strings I've tried:

```
"SQL_Server": "Data Source=[SQL server Address];Initial Catalog=Investment_Dev;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=true"

"SQL_Server": "Data Source=[SQL server Address];Initial Catalog=Investment_Dev;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=true"
```

My configuration for IIS is as follows

In `Authentication` all is set to `Disabled` except for `Windows Authentication` which is set to `Enabled`.

In `Configuration Editor` -> `system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication` I've set `useAppPoolCredentials` to `False`

For my sites `Edit Site` I have `Connect As` set to `Application user (pass-through authentication)`

In my application pools, I have the pools `Managed pipeline mode` set to `Integrated`, `Identity` set to a service account I've set up to handle incoming requests, `Load User Profile` set to `False` and I've tried it set to `True`

While I've recreated a new `dbcontext` in the method above to test solutions my application does use a `DbContextFactory` normally to get data from the DB.

In `Startup.cs` I've set it up in the following way.

```
using Impersonation_Test_Project.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddDbContextFactory<SqlDboDbContext>(opt => opt
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQL_Server")));
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

Comment: Run your site's IIS app pool as user X ?

Comment: Since my DB is setup with Row level security won't that just show all connecting users that one users specific rows and none of their own?

Comment: Yes.. my bad; i didnt realize you were looking to authenticate to that level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Auth doesn't imply impersonation.  So normally your code runs as your app pool identity, so that's what `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns.

See eg, [ASP.NET Impersonation Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-4-configure-application-security#aspnet-impersonation-authentication)

You can use SQL Server Row Level Security without impersonation, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15#MidTier).  Or you can grant your App Pool identity the privilege to perform SQL Server impersonation of your end users, and impersonate them inside SQL Server using [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of in Windows.